# I can't add option "-v" to console symfony

Tags: php, symfony, command, symfony-console

I want to add a command to my application console,

I can't add "-v" option to my code with `->addOption` to run my command console on symfony.

When i run the command with `bin/console app:cmd:name [option]`, an error appear:

```
An option with shortcut "v" already exists.
```

Comment: Doesnt the error tells your everything!? `-v` is verbose in all commands.

Comment: You can't use this option `v`, cause this parameter already reserved (`--version`) in the symfony.
Please use another option.

Comment: @vevovip Yes, the parameter is reserved. But not for `--version`.

Answer (score 3):

The `-v or -vv or -vvv` is a reserved "command shortcut" in Symfony to increase the verbosity of messages:

> 1 "-v" for normal output

> 2 "-vv" for more verbose output

> 3 "-vvv" for debug

So you have to use another shortcut for your command.

Also, you can take a closer look at the Symfony verbosity levels:
[Verbosity levels documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/verbosity.html)